# Consider last group with groupby

Tags: pandas, group-by

I'm just trying to understand `grouper` a little more. I know calling the `frequency` makes some functions void. But I was wondering if there was a work around to count the last segment when using  `grouper`. For example, I want the `max` count to include the 15min segment between `13:30:00 and 13:45:00` for the `df` below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : ['1904-01-01 13:00:00','1904-01-01 13:10:00','1904-01-01 13:15:00','1904-01-01 13:25:00','1904-01-01 13:35:00'],                 
    'Number' : [2,2,1,1,1],                      
    })

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15T', key='Time', closed = 'left'))['Number'].max().ffill()
df = df.reset_index(level=['Time'])
```

Out:

```
                 Time  Number
0 1904-01-01 13:00:00       2
1 1904-01-01 13:15:00       1
2 1904-01-01 13:30:00       1
```

This can be achieved by using the `label = 'right'`. But the output is:

```
                 Time  Number
0 1904-01-01 13:15:00       2
1 1904-01-01 13:30:00       1
2 1904-01-01 13:45:00       1
```

I'm hoping to return the `df`:

```
                 Time  Number
0 1904-01-01 13:00:00       2
1 1904-01-01 13:15:00       1
2 1904-01-01 13:30:00       1
3 1904-01-01 13:45:00       1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get different output in pandas 0.24.2:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15T', key='Time', closed = 'right'))['Number'].max().ffill()
df = df.reset_index(level=['Time'])
print (df)
                 Time  Number
0 1904-01-01 12:45:00       2
1 1904-01-01 13:00:00       2
2 1904-01-01 13:15:00       1
3 1904-01-01 13:30:00       1
```

Labels is possible shift by [`label='right'`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48340463/2901002), but values are not changed:

```
df = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15T', key='Time', label='right', closed = 'right'))['Number']
       .max().ffill())

#resample alternative
df2 = df.resample('15T', on='Time', label='right', closed='right')['Number'].max().ffill()
df2 = df.reset_index(level=['Time'])
print (df2)
                 Time  Number
0 1904-01-01 13:00:00       2
1 1904-01-01 13:15:00       2
2 1904-01-01 13:30:00       1
3 1904-01-01 13:45:00       1
```

More information are found in [how to understand closed and label arguments in pandas resample method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48340463/2901002), because same logic is used for `Grouper` and most parameters are same.

Possible solution for your problem is add new row with shifted max datetime by `15 Min`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': df['Time'].max() + pd.Timedelta('15T'),
                    'Number':df['Number'].iat[-1]}, index=[0])
print (df1)
                 Time  Number
0 1904-01-01 13:50:00       1

df = df.append(df1).groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15T', key='Time'))['Number'].max()
df = df.reset_index(level=['Time'])

print (df)
                 Time  Number
0 1904-01-01 13:00:00       2
1 1904-01-01 13:15:00       1
2 1904-01-01 13:30:00       1
3 1904-01-01 13:45:00       1
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I did consider adding a new row at the end of the df. I just didn't know if there was a function I was missing that could perform the same task.